# SQL Trigger to split string during insert without a common delimiter and store it into another table

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

Currently I have a system that is dumping data into a table with the format:

```
Table1
Id#, row#, row_dump
222, 1, “set1  = aaaa     set2 =aaaaaa  aaaa  dd set4=1111”
```

I want to take the row dump and transpose it into rows and insert it into another table of the format:

```
Table2
Id#, setting, value
222, ‘set1’,’aaa’ 
222, ‘set2’,’aaaaaa  aaaa  dd’
222, ‘set4’,’1111’
```

Is there a way to make a trigger in MSSQL that will parse this string on insert in Table1 and insert it into Table2 properly?

All of the examples I’ve found required a common delimiter. ‘=’ separates the setting from the value, space(s) separate a value from a setting but a value could have spaces in it (settings do not have spaces in them so the last word before the equal sign is the setting name but there could be spaces between the setting name and equal sign).

There could be 1-5 settings and values in any given row. The values can have spaces. There may or may not be space between the setting name and the ‘=’ sign.

I have no control over the original insert process or format as it is used for other purposes.

Comment: This is probably possible in pure sql, but sounds like it would be easier to solve with a procedural language. What do you use for programming this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use 'set' as a delimiter.  This is a simple sample.  It obviously may have to be molded to your environment.

```
use tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_TVF_Split') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_TVF_Split;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_TVF_Split(@arr AS NVARCHAR(2000), @sep AS NCHAR(3))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH 
   L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1)       --2 rows
  ,L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B)    --4 rows (2x2)
  ,L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B)    --16 rows (4x4)
  ,L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B)    --256 rows (16x16)
  ,L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L3 AS A, L3 AS B)    --65536 rows (256x256)
  ,L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L4 AS A, L4 AS B)    --4,294,967,296 rows (65536x65536)
  ,Nums AS (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS N FROM L5)  
SELECT
(n - 1) - LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@arr, n-1), @sep, N'')) + 1 AS pos,
SUBSTRING(@arr, n, CHARINDEX(@sep, @arr + @sep, n) - n) AS element
FROM Nums
WHERE 
    n <= LEN(@arr) + 3
    AND SUBSTRING(@sep + @arr, n, 3) = @sep
    AND N<=100000
GO

declare @t table(
Id int,
row int,
row_dump varchar(Max)
);

insert into @t values(222, 1, 'set1 = aaaa set2 =aaaaaa aaaa dd set4=1111')
insert into @t values(111, 2, ' set1 =cx set2 =4444set4=124')

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
Id int,
Setting VARCHAR(6),
[Value] VARCHAR(50)
)

insert into @t2 (Id,Setting,Value)
select 
    Id,
    [Setting]='set' + left(LTRIM(element),1),
    [Value]=RIGHT(element,charindex('=',reverse(element))-1)
from @t t
cross apply dbo.fn_TVF_Split(row_dump,'set')
where pos > 1
order by 
    id asc, 
    'set' + left(LTRIM(element),1) asc

select *
from @t2
```

### Update

You could do something like this.  It is not optimal and could probably be better handled in the transformation tool or application. Anyway here we go.

Note: You will need the split function I posted before.

```
declare @t table(
Id int,
row int,
row_dump varchar(Max)
);

insert into @t values(222, 1, 'set1 = aaaa set2 =aaaaaa aaaa dd set3=abc set4=1111 set5=7373')
insert into @t values(111, 2, 'set1 =cx set2 = 4444 set4=124')

DECLARE @t2 TABLE(
Id int,
Setting VARCHAR(6),
[Value] VARCHAR(50)
)

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Vals') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #Vals;
END

CREATE TABLE #Vals(
Id INT,
Row INT,
Element VARCHAR(MAX),
pos int,
value VARCHAR(MAX)
);

insert into #Vals
select 
    Id,
    row,
    element,
    pos,
    Value=STUFF(LEFT(element,len(element) - CHARINDEX(' ',reverse(element))),1,1,'')
from(
    select 
        Id,
        row,
        row_dump = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(row_dump,'= ','='),' =','='),'=','=|')
    from @t
) AS t
cross apply dbo.fn_TVF_Split(row_dump,'=')
where pos >=1 and pos < 10


insert into @t2 (Id,Setting,Value)
select 
    t1.Id,
    Setting =
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            CASE WHEN t2.pos = 1 
                 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(t2.element))
            ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(t2.element,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(t2.element)))))
            END
        FROM #Vals t2 
        where 
            t2.Id = t1.id 
            and t2.row = t1.row 
            and t2.pos < t1.pos 
        ORDER BY t2.pos DESC
    ),
    t1.Value
from #Vals t1
where t1.pos > 1 and t1.pos < 10
order by t1.id,t1.row,t1.pos

select * from @t2
```

Comment: ‘set’ would not work as a delimiter. That was just a flaw in my example. Anything listed as ‘set’ could be any alpha numeric word before the equal sign.

Comment: I modified my post to meet the new data.  Again, I would propose that this solution be moved into the application tier or the process that is doing the initial loading.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I understand it’s not the best way to solve the program but my situation is not ideal. The data is coming from a program that request information via terminal interface and dumps the text to a sql file that is imported into the database (which I can’t touch). The program that creates the sql file is not very good at parsing data; you have to tell it give command ‘x’ then look for value two rows down from column 18 to 30.

Comment: But that would be difficult as there are 1000+ of these settings and I would have to define location for each one. Plus each firmware and model puts the responses in different locations basically it would take a lifetime define every combination I have. So I’m left with doing the parsing on the backend or during a night batch but I’m looking for an SQL solution because of company rules about internally software development on secured systems.